# What is the size limit for PostgreSQL 9.0+ hstore?

Tags: database, postgresql

As title, I have been searching around for a while and not able to find an answer. It only states key and value can't be longer than 65535 when it's on 8.4, but not being mentioned at all on 9.0 documentation.

Comment: My guess is, that this is now limited by the size of a single column (i.e. 1GB) - but again that's just a guess. You might have more luck posting this question on the Postgres mailing list.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`hstore` is a varlena, and is limited by the maximum size of `TOAST`ed fields, about 1GB.

I do not recommend that you go anywhere near the size. Performance will be awful. Every time you update a row - including rows with `hstore` fields - PostgreSQL must write a new copy of the row. Needless to say, with gigabyte rows that's not going to be fun.

Read performance will be OK if you're reading all the keys/values, but poor if you're selectively reading just a few keys/values, as the `hstore` must be de-`TOAST`ed before access.

It's hard to give more specific advice without knowing your design and use case; the *why* of this question.

Comment: Well I just want to know the limit, and thanks for your answer, this is quite useful. So indeed a serialisation does occur when you write the field? Sounds like thats not something very brilliant then comparing to genuine NoSQL storage.

Comment: @goodwill `hstore` is useful, but it's not a database-in-a-field. I've seen a few questions about it recently that suggest people are contemplating trying to store whole fast-changing data sets in single `hstore` fields. This is a terrible idea. `hstore` is often a good alternative to storing EAV-structured data or using JSON/XML etc, but it's more at the "document" than "database" level. Even EAV can be better if the data is fast-changing.